# Problemas en la Implementación del método sample de random en python

Tags: python

Hola necesito obtener de un modelo una combinación diferente cada vez que lo llamo.
Para eso utilizo sample pero algo estoy haciendo mal (sino todo) por que me devuelve resultados repetidos.

```
mod =[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4),(5,5,5),(6,6,6)]

print(random.sample(mod,1))
print(random.sample(mod,1))
print(random.sample(mod,1))
print(random.sample(mod,1))
print(random.sample(mod,1))
print(random.sample(mod,1))
```

Por ejemplo ese código me devolvió esto

```
[(3, 3, 3)]
[(5, 5, 5)]
[(6, 6, 6)]
[(6, 6, 6)]
[(6, 6, 6)]
[(6, 6, 6)]
```

Y la idea es que me baraje de algún modo y siempre obtenga de las 6 tuplas internas una combinación diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecutar varias veces sample no va a evitar que se repitan los resultados. El llamado actual a sample no sabe que ya ha sido llamado antes con la misma secuencia. En su lugar usa sample una sola vez (para eso está pensado). El segundo argumento nos dice el tamaño de la muestra que vamos a obtener (vos le ponés 1, por lo que te devuelve un solo caso). Si queremos todos los casos tendremos que usar `len(mod)` que nos devolverá el numero de items en la lista.

El código correcto, en conclusión, sería:

```
mod =[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4),(5,5,5),(6,6,6)]
print(random.sample(mod, len(mod)))
```

Incluso puedes usar random.shuffle si se trata de una secuencia mutable (como una lista) y te ahorras el len(mod). Esto modifica la lista original, por lo que no es necesario guardar ningún resultado en ninguna variable.

```
mod =[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4),(5,5,5),(6,6,6)]
random.suffle(mod)
print(mod)
```

###### Referencias

- [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#random.sample)
- [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: Pero pues lo que es saber!!! Muchas gracias Dante!. Hace poco estoy trabajando en Python y estaba errando feo.

Comment: De nada El pibe bazooka c: